# Spinner Data Connectivity issue- data binding successful but spinner shows blank text

Tags: android, spinner

i have been trying to bind spinner to a database and finally got succeeded. i have connected spinner to database table using cursoradapter. but the problem is the spinner gets populated but the list items in it shows blank text. i know binding is successful because it shows as many rows as there are records in database table.
can not figure out what it is. some body please help i am stuck here
i am posting the code below

```
public long createAccount() {

    ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues();
    Log.i("DB", initialValues.get(KEY_NAME)+":"+
            initialValues.get(KEY_MAILBOXTYPE)+":"+
            initialValues.get(KEY_OUTPORT)+":"+
            initialValues.get(KEY_INPORT)+":"+
            initialValues.get(KEY_INSERVER)+":"+
            initialValues.get(KEY_OUTSERVER)+":");
    return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}



/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all todo in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAccount() {
    Log.i("DB", "Cursor opened");

    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
             KEY_NAME,KEY_INSERVER}, null, null, null,
            null, null);



}
```

Code for spinner binding is below:

```
                mAccAdap.createAccount();

                Cursor c = mAccAdap.fetchAccount();        
                startManagingCursor(c);
                SimpleCursorAdapter CursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,
                        new String[]{mAccAdap.KEY_INSERVER},new int[]{R.id.tvDBViewRow});

                            CursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                            spinEmail=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinAccount);
                            spinEmail.setAdapter(CursorAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this part of your `SimpleCursorAdapter`...

`new int[]{R.id.tvDBViewRow}`

to this...

`new int[]{android.R.id.text1}`

Comment: wow. it worked. thanks a lot. but can you also please explain the reason behind it.

Comment: It is because you specified a built in Android template with this line `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` ... Within this template there is an element with the id of "text1". When you tried to reference `R.id.tvDBViewRow` it was not there because that id is not in the layout template XML. You could of course create your own layout XML for use in this `SimpleCursorAdapter` and then reference your own `TextView`.